# Prestahop Order Webservice Issue

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop-1.6

Trying to put an order via webservice. I've followed the correct order via webservice:

1. Create customer (customers blank schema)
2. Create customer's address (addresses blank schema)
3. Create associated customer's cart(carts blank schema)
4. Create Order (orders blank schema)

The problem is when order will be created and saved in database. I've launched the function which imports data into client + address + cart + order; aparently everything works fine, client, address and cart was created correctly, but not the order...

I've tested on php 5.6.30 server on my localhost lap and everything works fine but in a production php 5.5.9 server orders won't be created...

This is the function to create order:

```
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH .'api/orders/?schema=blank'));

$pedido = $xml->children()->children();

$direccion  = getDireccion($idCliente, $webService);
$carrito    = getCarrito($idCarrito, $webService);

$numProdPedido = count($carrito->associations->cart_rows->cart_row);


$pedido->id_address_delivery    = $direccion['address']['id']; // Customer address
$pedido->id_address_invoice     = $direccion['address']['id'];
$pedido->id_cart                = $idCarrito;
$pedido->id_currency            = $carrito->id_currency;
$pedido->id_lang                = $carrito->id_lang;
$pedido->mp_order_id            = $refPedido;
$pedido->reference              = $refPedido;
$pedido->id_customer            = $carrito->id_customer;
$pedido->id_carrier             = $carrito->id_carrier;
$pedido->payment                = $refPedido;//$pedido_ws['paymentType'];
$pedido->module                 = 'cashondelivery';
$pedido->total_paid             = $pedido_ws['total_price'];
$pedido->total_paid_real        = $pedido_ws['total_price'];
$pedido->total_products         = $numProdPedido;
$pedido->total_products_wt      = $numProdPedido;
$pedido->conversion_rate        = 1;
// Others
$pedido->valid                      = '1';
$pedido->current_state              = '1';
getEstadoPedido($pedido->order_state);
$pedido->total_discounts            = $pedido_ws['promotions']['total_deduced_amount'];
$pedido->total_discounts_tax_incl   = $pedido_ws['promotions']['total_deduced_amount'];
$pedido->total_discounts_tax_excl   = $pedido_ws['promotions']['total_deduced_amount'];
$pedido->total_paid_tax_incl        = $pedido_ws['total_price'];
$pedido->total_paid_tax_excl        = $pedido_ws['total_price'];
$pedido->total_shipping             = $pedido_ws['shipping_price'];
$pedido->total_shipping_tax_incl    = $pedido_ws['shipping_price'];
$pedido->total_shipping_tax_excl    = $pedido_ws['shipping_price'];
$ind = 0;
foreach($carrito->associations->cart_rows->cart_row as $producto){

    $prod = getProductoById($producto->id_product, $webService);
    $pedido->associations->order_rows->order_row[$ind]->product_id                = $producto->id_product;
    $pedido->associations->order_rows->order_row[$ind]->product_attribute_id      = $producto->id_product_attribute;
    $pedido->associations->order_rows->order_row[$ind]->product_quantity          = $producto->quantity;
    $pedido->associations->order_rows->order_row[$ind]->product_name              = $prod->name->language[0];
    $pedido->associations->order_rows->order_row[$ind]->product_reference         = $prod->reference;
    $pedido->associations->order_rows->order_row[$ind]->product_price             = $prod->price;
    $pedido->associations->order_rows->order_row[$ind]->unit_price_tax_incl       = $prod->price;
    $pedido->associations->order_rows->order_row[$ind]->unit_price_tax_excl       = $prod->price;

    $ind++;
}
// Creating the order
$opt = ['resource' => 'orders'];
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->add($opt);
```

Any clues?

Edit: XML request and response code when calling order webservice. This is the last order xml.

```
HTTP REQUEST HEADER
POST //api/orders HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic WDMxSlRJRjFTNTNIMVlTS0hZRUFHTjlJVk5CQ1ZHTlg6
Host: www.mywebsite.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 1956
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

HTTP RESPONSE HEADER
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 26 Apr 2017 10:08:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Authorization,Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19
Set-Cookie: PrestaShop-300d307acc0ec8525a71119b0dd393d8=0XUqFuC%2BvHy%2B%2BAU8Uod5odM7En0QQlQNh2ZWuI7VO6wTSlgh%2F%2FlVEDyz4e%2BJUv55b3N6fHTdEz%2Fmyjob65wxqjofdRVglsNIauli6yfcEBQ%3D000079; expires=Tue, 16-May-2017 10:08:05 GMT; Max-Age=1727999; path=/; domain=www.mywebsite.com; httponly
XML SENT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<order>
<id/>
<id_address_delivery>31754</id_address_delivery>
<id_address_invoice>31754</id_address_invoice>
<id_cart>1314430</id_cart>
<id_currency>1</id_currency>
<id_lang>1</id_lang>
<id_customer>22578</id_customer>
<id_carrier>1</id_carrier>
<current_state>3</current_state>
<module>cashondelivery</module>
<invoice_number/>
<invoice_date/>
<delivery_number/>
<delivery_date/>
<valid>1</valid>
<date_add/>
<date_upd/>
<shipping_number/>
<id_shop_group/>
<id_shop/>
<secure_key/>
<payment>40862744-A</payment>
<recyclable/>
<gift/>
<gift_message/>
<mobile_theme/>
<total_discounts>0</total_discounts>
<total_discounts_tax_incl>0</total_discounts_tax_incl>
<total_discounts_tax_excl>0</total_discounts_tax_excl>
<total_paid>25.98</total_paid>
<total_paid_tax_incl>25.98</total_paid_tax_incl>
<total_paid_tax_excl>25.98</total_paid_tax_excl>
<total_paid_real>25.98</total_paid_real>
<total_products>1</total_products>
<total_products_wt>1</total_products_wt>
<total_shipping>2.99</total_shipping>
<total_shipping_tax_incl>2.99</total_shipping_tax_incl>
<total_shipping_tax_excl>2.99</total_shipping_tax_excl>
<carrier_tax_rate/>
<total_wrapping/>
<total_wrapping_tax_incl/>
<total_wrapping_tax_excl/>
<round_mode/>
<conversion_rate>1</conversion_rate>
<reference/>
<associations>
<order_rows>
<order_row>
<id/>
<product_id>233154</product_id>
<product_attribute_id>0</product_attribute_id>
<product_quantity>1</product_quantity>
<product_name>Smartwatch Gt08 Sim sd bluetooth Negro plata</product_name>
<product_reference>8435338885678</product_reference>
<product_ean13/>
<product_upc/>
<product_price>25.920000</product_price>
<unit_price_tax_incl>25.920000</unit_price_tax_incl>
<unit_price_tax_excl>25.920000</unit_price_tax_excl>
</order_row>
</order_rows>
</associations>
</order>
</prestashop>
```

RETURN HTTP BODY
**Here is blank space, don't know if there will be some response xml code...

Comment: It sounds like a typo but without any code we really can not help you..

Comment: You've got some code @AntonisTsimourtos =)

Comment: Does the xml contains all the data that you expect? Have you enabled error logging?

Comment: Yes, the XML contains all the required data and error reporting and debug is enabled... I'm gonna edit the post and add some XML response @AntonisTsimourtos

Comment: Now you can see request and response xml retrieved by webservice @AntonisTsimourtos

Comment: So you have all the data but some of them are not stored into the database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142714/discussion-between-makros-and-antonis-tsimourtos).

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I'm getting all data but only Client, Address and Cart are stored on database. When manage order XML to save into database, no error and obviously, not saved anything...

Comment: Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these to an empty string. If that doesn't work try setting it to your product ID.

```
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[$i]->product_attribute_id
```

and

```
$xml->cart->associations->cart_rows->cart_row[$i]->id_product_attribute
```